# CSS/HTML Bug on full width image / small space under the image is shown

Tags: html, css

on my website i use a image as seperator between sections. You can see this seperator on this image:

[section seperator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5m9A.png)

On the image you also see the bug. There ist a small line under the image.

Here ist the implementation:

HTML:

```
<img className="lineBreakTopWhite" style={{width: "100%" ,display: "block"}} src={TopShape} />
```

CSS:

```
.lineBreakTopWhite {background-image: url('./img/Verlauf.png');}
```

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding...

```
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
```

...to the image separator.

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't solves the problem. Still the line below the image. If integrate the border-bottom, the line is under the border.

Comment: Can you post the Verlauf.png file?